# Looking for a real time streaming solution

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming, akka-stream

We have a spark-streaming micro batch process which consumes data from kafka topic with 20 partitions. The data in the partitions are independent and can be processed independently. The current problem is the micro batch waits for processing to be complete in all 20 partitions before starting next micro batch. So if one partition completes processing in 10 seconds and other partition takes 2 mins then the first partition will have to wait for 110 seconds before consuming next offset.

I am looking for a streaming solution where we can process the 20 partitions independently without having to wait for other partition to complete a process. The steaming solution should consume data from each partition and progress offsets at its own rate independent of other partitions.

Anyone have suggestion on which streaming architecture would allow to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of Flink (AFAIK), KStreams, and Akka Streams will be able to progress through the partitions independently: none of them does Spark-style batching unless you explicitly opt in.

Flink is similar to Spark in that it has a job server model; KStreams and Akka are both libraries that you just integrate into your project and deploy like any other JVM application (e.g. you can build a container and run on a scheduler like kubernetes).  I personally prefer the latter approach: it generally means less infrastructure to worry about and less of an impedance mismatch to integrate with observability tooling used elsewhere.

Flink is an especially good choice when it comes to time-window based processing and joins.

KStreams fundamentally models everything as a transformation from one kafka topic to another: the topic topology is managed by KStreams, but there can be some gotchas there (especially if you're dealing with anything time-seriesy).

Akka is the most general and (in some senses) the least opinionated of the toolkits: you will have to make more decisions with less handholding (I'm saying this as someone who could probably fairly be called an Akka cheerleader); as a pure stream processing library, it may not be the ideal choice (though in terms of resource consumption, being able to more explicitly manage backpressure (basically, what happens when data comes in faster than it can be processed) may make it more efficient than the alternatives).  I'd probably tend to only choose it if you were going to also take advantage of cluster sharded (and almost certainly event-sourced) actors: the benefit of doing that is that you can completely decouple your processing parallelism from the number of input Kafka partitions (e.g. you may be able to deploy 40 instances of processing and have each working on half of the data from Kafka).